# TypeError: Model constructor takes no positional arguments

Tags: python, rest, google-app-engine

While creating an answer for a question in the API (see code below), I got the following error:

> TypeError: Model constructor takes no positional arguments

Can someone tell me how to solve this? I am using ndb model

```
import webapp2
import json
from google.appengine.ext  import ndb

class AnswerExchange(ndb.Model):
    answer=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False,default="No Message")

class AnswerHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
    def create_answer(self,question_id):
        try:
            query = StackExchange.query(StackExchange.questionId == question_id)        
            questions = query.fetch(1)
            ans_json = json.loads(self.request.body)

            answerObj = AnswerExchange(answer=ans_json["answer"])                
            answerObj.put()
            questions.answerName=answerObj

            questions.put()                
        except:
            raise webapp2.exc.HTTPBadRequest()

class StackExchange(ndb.Model):
    questionId=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    questionName=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    #answerID=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    answerName=ndb.StructuredProperty(AnswerExchange,repeated=True)


class StackHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):   
    def get_questions(self):
        #p = self.request.get('p')    #get QueryString Parameter
        #self.response.write(p)
        query = StackExchange.query()
        questions = query.fetch(6)
        self.response.content_type = 'application/json'
        self.response.write(json.dumps([d.to_dict() for d in questions]))

    def get_question(self, question_id):
        query = StackExchange.query(StackExchange.questionId == question_id)        
        questions = query.fetch(1)
        self.response.content_type = 'application/json'
        self.response.write(json.dumps([d.to_dict() for d in questions]))

    def create_question(self):
        try:
            question_json = json.loads(self.request.body)
            # if id in dept_json:
            questionNo = question_json["questionId"]
            questionToUpdate = StackExchange.query(StackExchange.questionId == questionNo);
            #print deptToUpdate.count()
            if questionToUpdate.count() == 0:            
                question = StackExchange(questionId=question_json["questionId"], questionName=question_json["questionName"])                
            else:
                question = questionToUpdate.get()
                question.questionName = question_json["questionName"]

            #key = dept.put()
            question.put()                
        except:
            raise webapp2.exc.HTTPBadRequest()

        self.response.headers['Location'] = webapp2.uri_for('get_question', question_id=questionNo)
        self.response.status_int = 201
        self.response.content_type = 'application/json'
        #self.response.write(json.dumps())

    def create_answer(self,question_id):
        #try:
            question_json = json.loads(self.request.body)
            questionNo = question_json["questionId"]
            query = StackExchange.query(StackExchange.questionId == questionNo)        
            questions = query.fetch(1)
            ans_json = json.loads(self.request.body)

            answerObj = AnswerExchange(ans_json["answer"])                

            #answerObj.put()
            #self.response.write(ans_json["answerName"])
            questions.answerName =  answerObj
            questions.put();             
        #except:
        #    raise webapp2.exc.HTTPBadRequest()


    def get_answer(self, question_id):
        query = StackExchange.query(StackExchange.questionId == question_id)        
        questions = query.fetch(1)
        self.response.content_type = 'application/json'
        self.response.write(json.dumps([d.to_dict() for d in questions]))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/api/v1/questions/<question_id>', methods=['GET'], handler='api.StackHandler:get_question', name='get_question'),
    webapp2.Route(r'/api/v1/questions', methods=['GET'], handler='api.StackHandler:get_questions', name='get_questions'), 
    webapp2.Route(r'/api/v1/questions', methods=['POST'], handler='api.StackHandler:create_question', name='create_question'),
    webapp2.Route(r'/api/v1/questions/<question_id>/answers', methods=['POST'], handler='api.StackHandler:create_answer', name='create_answer'),
    webapp2.Route(r'/api/v1/questions/<question_id>/answers', methods=['GET'], handler='api.StackHandler:get_answer', name='get_answer')
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Please paste the whole traceback too

Answer (score 1):

Change,

```
answerObj = AnswerExchange(ans_json["answer"])
```

in `create_answer` method `StackHandler` class

to

```
answerObj = AnswerExchange(answer=ans_json["answer"])
```